# Populate PieChart based on SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-express, teechart

I have the following stored procedure that I have to get data from:

```
   EXECUTE [dbo].[StationHealthStatusSummary2]
            @LineId varchar(100),        // 5,9,10
            @MeasurementDt datetime,    //2012/06/06
            @Ntotal Int output,
            @N0 int output,
            @N1 int output,
            @N2 int output,
            @N3 int output,
            @N4 int output,
            @N5 int output,
            @N6 int output,
            @N7 int output,
            @N8 int output,
            @N9 int output,
            @N10 int output,
            @N11 int output,
            @N12 int output,
            @N13 int output,
            @N14 int output,
            @N15 int output,
            @N16 int output
       GO
```

Now I can send parameters to `LineID` and `Measurement` date as follows:

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=iComs;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Password);

SqlCommand getData = new SqlCommand("StationHealthStatusSummary2", sql);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getData);

getData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
getData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LineId", Lines));
getData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MeasurementDt", date1));

SqlParameter ParamaterNtotal = new SqlParameter();
ParamaterNtotal.ParameterName = "@Ntotal";
ParamaterNtotal.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
ParamaterNtotal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
getData.Parameters.Add(ParamaterNtotal);

sql.Open();

getData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I can get the value of `NTotal` and assign it to a Teechart (PieSlice),
but how do I get the value for `@N0..@N16`?

I've got some code that might give you some idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
int NTotal = int.Parse(getData.Parameters["@Ntotal"].Value.ToString());

if (GetVariantVariableI(getData.Parameters[0].Value) = 0)
{               
    for (c = 1; c <= 18; c++)
    { 
        Nvl = GetVariantVariableI(getData.Parameters[2+c].Value);

        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
                NTotal = Nvl;
                break;

            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:                           
            case 12:                            
            case 13:                           
            case 14:                           
            case 15:                            
            case 16:                           
            case 17:
            case 18:
            case 19:
            case 20:
                cstatus = c-2;
                NPieValues[cstatus] = Nvl;
                break;
   }   

   string SliceName;
   int NUsed;

   NUsed = 0;

   for(i=0;i<=16;i++)
   {
      NUsed = NUsed + NPieValues[i];
   }

   if (NUsed < NTotal)
   {
       Chart1.Series[0].Add(NTotal - NUsed);
       slice1.Title = "Not Connected";
       slice1.Add();
       slice1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
   }

   if (NUsed > NTotal)
   {
      NPieValues[7] = NPieValues[7]-(NUsed-NTotal);
   }

   for (i=0;i<=16;i++)
   {
     if (NPieValues[i]>0)
     {
         switch(i)
         {
            case 0: SliceName ="Green"; 
                    break;
            case 1: SliceName ="Yellow";
                    break;
            case 2: SliceName ="Orange";
                    break;
            case 3: SliceName ="Red";
                    break;
            case 4: SliceName ="Broken Rail";
                    break;
            case 5: SliceName ="Buckling Rail";
                    break;
            case 6: SliceName ="Maintenance required";
                    break;
            case 7: SliceName ="Station(s) Off";
                    break;
            case 8: SliceName ="Rail Differential kN";
                    break;
            case 9: SliceName ="Left Rail Sensor Faulty";
                    break;
            case 10: SliceName ="Right Rail Sensor Faulty";
                     break;
            case 11: SliceName ="Temperature Rail Sensor Faulty";
                     break;
            case 12: SliceName ="Calibration Required";
                     break;
            case 13: SliceName ="Station Vandalised";
                     break;
            case 14: SliceName ="Station uninstalled";
                     break;
            case 15: SliceName ="Gauges removed for Maintenance";
                     break;
            case 16: SliceName ="No GSM Coverage";
                     break;
            default:
                     SliceName ="?";
         }
         switch(i)
         {
          case 0: clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Green";
                 break;
          case 1:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Yellow";
                 break;
          case 2:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Orrange";
                 break;
          case 3:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Red";
                 break;
          case 4:
          case 5:
          case 8:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Purple";
                 break;
          case 6:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Black";
                 break;
          case 7:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Gray";
                 break;;
          case 9:clr = "System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml('#E0671F')";
                 break;
          case 10:clr = "System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml('#BA4EC2')";
                 break;
          case  11:clr = "System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml('#FF8000')";
                 break;
          case  12:clr =  "System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml('#BF4093')";
                 break;
          case  13:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.SkyBlue";
                 break;
          case 14:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.Aqua";
                 break;
          case 15:clr = "System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml('#BFBFFF')";
                 break;                 
          case 16:clr = "System.Drawing.Color.MedGray";
                 break;
             default : clr = "System.Drawing.Color.White";
                 break;              
         }
      slice1.Add(NPieValues[i],SliceName,clr);
     }

 }
            }
        }

    }
```

Now after it got all those values it has to populate the piechart.

Please, any help will be highly appreciated and please tell me if I'm being too vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `@Ntotal` as an Output parameter, why didn't you add all the others?

```
SqlParameter n = new SqlParameter();
n.ParameterName = "@N0";
n.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
n.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
getData.Parameters.Add(n);
```

Then you can retrieve the output values the same way you do with `@Ntotal`. Also, you can retrieve the values by name instead of looping through them, if you prefer.

Comment: already did all that as you explain, but how do i add that to the piechart? and how do i implement all the case statements to it?

Comment: also, is there an easier(quicker)way i can send those parameters? instead of having to write all 18 out?

Comment: You could return the values as part of a `SELECT` statement instead of the individual parameters, but that will increase the amount of code you need to write to support a `DataTable` on the client side. So either way, you will have a fair amount of code.

Comment: As there doesn't appear to be much in the way of examples on the TeeChart site (at least on the free side), wasn't there any documentation or support with your paid license?

Comment: I just tried doing all the parameters 1 by one and assigned the return value to a label, but the return values are 0?

Comment: i want to take things step by step first. i will worry about adding the values to the piechart after i get the correct return values.

Comment: Perhaps you are not assigning values to the params in the stored proc? It's hard to tell, that code is not included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I Figured it out... 
after i send the parameters as follows:

```
    SqlParameter Paramater0 = new SqlParameter();
        Paramater0.ParameterName = "@N0";
        Paramater0.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        Paramater0.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        getData.Parameters.Add(Paramater0);
```

I then get the value and declare it to a var as follows:

```
     int N0 = int.Parse(getData.Parameters["@N0"].Value.ToString());
```

and finally declare that int to a slice on the chart as follows:

```
     slice1.Add(N0, "Green", System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```

Thanks for your help @mgnoonan :)